# stop object while falling

Tags: unity, c#, physics

[image]

The object have `forwardForce`.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb; 
    public float forwardForce=800f;
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.AddForce(0,0,forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);
        if(Input.GetKey("d")){
            rb.AddForce(30 * Time.deltaTime,0,0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }else if(Input.GetKey("a")){
            rb.AddForce(-30 * Time.deltaTime,0,0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);   
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the issue is I want to stop that object while falling down(not on that ground anymore).The camera will keep running but, I just want to stop that object. Which means if the is not on ground anymore than `velocity=0`

[image]

Comment: you want to reset the level, teleport the player back on the track or just stop the camera from following? can your player jump (or is a simple ground check enough to determinate if he fell off).

Comment: @Zibelas No! I don't wanna reset. Look while the object is falling the `z` axis increasing which means the object is traveling through `z` axis. I want not to change the `z` axis the object is falling.

Comment: You can lock the axis to prevent rotation

Comment: @Zibelas Sorry! I am new to game development. I couldn't get you. How to lock the axis?

Comment: Take a look at the constraint properties of the rigidbody of your object

Comment: @Zibelas I froze `z` axis but, the object isn't moving anymore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119529/discussion-between-zibelas-and-istiak).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb; 
    public float forwardForce=1000f;
    

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.AddForce(0,0,forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);
        if(Input.GetKey("d")){
            rb.AddForce(30 * Time.deltaTime,0,0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }else if(Input.GetKey("a")){
            rb.AddForce(-30 * Time.deltaTime,0,0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);   
        }
        if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position,Vector3.down,0.5f)==false){
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.y, 0);
        }else{
            
        }
    }
}
```

I tried by detecting the player is `onGrounded` or not. Then, I set velocity = 0 if player isn't grounded

Thanks [Zibelas](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/75244/zibelas)